# SSH session terminates while tail -f running

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, timeout, tail

For the past year or so, I have found that if I leave a 'tail -f' command running in my terminals for more than a few minutes, the SSH session will disconnect. Before the disconnection occurs, the terminal starts to become sluggish in so much as pressing Ctrl-C to cancel the tail command takes progressively longer to respond, the longer I leave the tail running. After the Ctrl-C is eventually handled, all is fine again.

Without a tail command running, the sessions will remain active indefinitely. I have not made any config changes to sshd and do not have any TMOUT setting in my terminal.

Google and SO have not yet revealed anything helpful to me on this.

I am presently using Ubuntu 18.04, and am connecting via Putty.

Comment: What are you tailing? Also, could you try with another ssh client?

Comment: Mostly log files (eg. apache logs), but it doesn't matter what I'm tailing - same thing happens consistently. I don't see much point in trying another ssh client - Putty has worked well for me and millions of others for 20+ years.

Comment: FWIW, I think I started observing this around the time I moved from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04, but am not certain.

Comment: Ok, I though you wanted to track down the issue. That usually involves checking everything, even things that worked for 20+ years :). Good luck then.

Comment: OK, smarty pants. I've a tail command running in both Putty and Mac Terminal now. So far, both running for half an hour or more without incident... ironic that the problem would seem to go away the moment I look for assistance, but will report back.